# Test data in behavior driven development

Tags: tdd, bdd, atdd

I read the bellow paragraph in an Acceptance test driven development master thesis. Is it right? If it is not, how we can use test data in BDD ?

**
The chapter proceeds with description of the main problem of BDD – it doesn’t suite any kind of software.BDD emphasizes behaviour and abstracts away test data to make tests look simple and readable.However, behaviour is not the only property making software complex. For
example, financial software has high amount of important data needed to be also
accessible by users of testing frameworks. The principle of abstracting such data
away doesn’t serve the purpose of a tool for improving communication between
stakeholders.**

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false.

There is nothing preventing one from using test data in the behaviour tests, integration tests or acceptance tests. For a quick sample see [Beyond the basics with Specflow](http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/beyond-the-basics/) and [SpecFlow Assist Helpers  on github](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers).

Answer (score 0):

Any test data used in scripted BDD tests (i.e. in C#) should really be given a contextual name.  Here is a C# test framework that provides BDD syntax for authoring tests directly in code.  It provides a means to name test data, for example.

```
var email = 'test@email.com'.Named("the users registration email");
```

or

```
var user = new User('test@email.com').Named("the registration user");
```

This can then be used in the testing.

Find the test framework here

- http://kernowcode.github.io/UBADDAS/